# Laravel save() shows undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and currently I am facing an issue.

I'm trying to insert a record to another database, but when I try to save it, it throws the below Error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

Here is my code:

```
$targetedCustomer = Customer::on($this->connection)->where('fusercode', $user->loginname)->first();
if($targetedCustomer->agent_code != $user->agent)
{
    $targetedCustomer->agent_code = $user->agent;
    $targetedCustomer->save();

    $logs = CustomerAgentCodeUpdateLog::on($this->connection);
    $logs->customer_id =  $targetedCustomer->customer_id;
    $logs->old_agent_code = $targetedCustomer->agent_code;
    $logs->new_agent_code = $user->agent;
    $logs->type = 1;
    $logs->save();
}
```

Comment: $logs->create();                        $logs->save();

Comment: validate first if `$targetedCustomer` is not null `if($targetedCustomer != null && $targetedCustomer->agent_code != $user->agent)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::on()` method returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class which doesn't have any method named `save()`. Therefore you have to do something like below to make it work:

```
$logs = CustomerAgentCodeUpdateLog::on($this->connection);

$logs->create([
    'customer_id' =>  $targetedCustomer->customer_id;
    'old_agent_code' => $targetedCustomer->agent_code;
    'new_agent_code' => $user->agent;
    'type' => 1;
]);
```

You don't need to call `save()`.

Comment: hi, when i used create() it was working, but the value passing inside all become null or 0 (if was integer). I've activated fillable at model

Comment: @Jake yes, because you have to use full `create($attributes)` method syntax which is passing `$attributes` as parameter to it. I have edited the answer, check it now and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method :

```
$targetedCustomer = Customer::on($this->connection)
    ->where('fusercode', $user->loginname)
    ->first();

if($targetedCustomer and $targetedCustomer->agent_code != $user->agent)
{
    // Set agent code
    $targetedCustomer->agent_code = $user->agent;
    $targetedCustomer->save();

    // New log
    $logs                 = (new CustomerAgentCodeUpdateLog)->on($this->connection); // with `new`
    $logs->customer_id    = $targetedCustomer->customer_id;
    $logs->old_agent_code = $targetedCustomer->agent_code;
    $logs->new_agent_code = $user->agent;
    $logs->type           = 1;
    $logs->save();
}
```